Speed at which the Moon moves past a point on Earth's surface?
I'm trying to calculate how fast a point on the surface of the Moon is moving past a point on the surface of the Earth (I assume a point on the equator of each for simplicity).
I know the Earth is rotating on its axis at 1,675 km/h at the equator. The Moon is revolving around the Earth at 3,683 km/h in the same direction as Earth's rotation, at a distance of 384,000 km from Earth's surface, and 390,778 km distant from the Earth's core (but does that matter?).
This is apparently more complex than it seems...

https://what-if.xkcd.com/157/ has some plots of "moon ground speed" which sounds like it might be what you are aiming for

I think this question isn't answerable for the same reason you're having trouble answering it... You haven't given a good definition of what you mean by "how fast a point on the surface of the Moon is moving past a point on the surface of the Earth." If you formulated a specific, clear definition of this concept, this would probably be easy to evaluate. One possible definition is "the magnitude of the relative velocity of one point on earth and one point on the moon". However this will be a very complicated formula, as it will depend on the longitude and latitude of the points you choose.

I have a Sage / Python script on https://space.stackexchange.com/a/61065/38535 that uses JPL data to create ground speed plots of Earth satellites.

The ground speed of the Moon can be thought of as the velocity of the bright spot on the surface of the Earth, projected from the Moon by a laser, pointing at the centre of the Earth, or as the lower end of a pole suspended from the Moon to just above the Earth's surface. (See Earth-Moon Fire Pole.)
Initially consider only the velocity of the Moon and ignore the rotation of the Earth. A point on the surface of the Earth that is on an imaginary line connecting the centre of the Moon to the centre of Earth moves slower than the tangential orbital velocity of the Moon because of the reduced radius. The Moon's ground velocity component ($V_{M}'$) due to the orbital velocity ($V_M$) of the Moon can be calculated using:
$V_{M}' = V_M \frac{R_E}{R_M}$
where $R_E$ is the radius of the Earth at the equator and $R_M$ is the radius of the Moon's orbit (which are definitely not to scale in the animation - the Moon is proportionately much further away).
Now we allow for contribution to the ground speed, due to the rotation of the Earth.

The left part of the animation depicts the point of view of an observer that is not rotating and hovering above the North pole. They see that the Earth's rotation is much faster than that of the Moon and the imaginary line connecting the Earth to Moon falls behind a fixed point of the surface of the Earth. The right half of the animation shows the point of view of a person on the equator who does not see the Earth as rotating. Instead, to them, the Moon appears to rotating in the opposite direction from East to West much like they see the Sun rotate in the same direction. The total velocity of the Moon track on the ground ($V_{G}$) is simply the component due to the moon's orbital rotation minus the component due to the Earth's rotation:
$V_{G} = V_{M}' - V_{E} = V_M \frac{R_E}{R_M} - V_{E} \approx$ -1,615 km/hr or about -450 m/s,
where $V_E$ is the tangential velocity of the Earth surface at the equator.
The simplifying assumptions used in the above calculation are:

The Earth and Moon are perfectly spherical.
The Moon's orbit is perfectly circular.
The Moon always remains directly above the Equator.
The Moon is perfectly tidally locked to the Earth.
Influences from other gravitational bodies in the Solar system are ignored.

Addendum: =================================
To generalise the calculations a bit beyond the simplified ones above so we can find the maximum and minimum values, let's consider a more detailed model:
In reality the Moon orbit is inclined to the equatorial plane of the Earth and this means the ground speed varies with latitude, being at a maximum at the equator and at a minimum at the poles. This requires finding the axial radius of the earth at a given latitude.  The distance from a point at a given latitude to the centre of the Earth is given by:
$$R' =  \frac{ P \ R_E }{\sqrt{R_E^2 \sin^2 \beta + P^2 \cos^2 \beta}}$$
where $R_E$ is the radius of the earth at the equator (6378 km), $P$ is the radius of the earth at a pole (6356 km) and $\beta$ is the latitude of the ground point from the equator. The above equation takes into account the earth's oblateness.
The contribution of the Earth's tangential velocity to the ground speed, when taking latitude into account is:
$\omega_{_{E}}' = -\omega_{_{E}}  R' \cos \beta = -V_E \frac{R' \cos \beta}{R_E}$
The Earth's angular velocity can be considered constant over thousands of years, but the Moon's angular velocity is continually changing because its distance from the Earth's centre (Min 363,300 km, Max 405,500 km) and it's tangential velocity (Min 3492 km/hr, Max 3895 km/hr) vary a lot from apogee to perigee, due to its elliptical orbit (Ref NASA Moon Factsheet).
The Moon's inclination to the ecliptic is 5.145 degrees, but the inclination of the Moon's orbit relative to the Earth's equatorial plane ($\phi$) varies from $\phi_{min} = 23.43-5.145 = $ 18.28 degrees to $\phi_{max} = 23.43+5.145 = $ 28.58 degrees due to the precession of the Moons orbit with a period of about 19 years. The earth's inclination (23.43 degrees) to the Ecliptic plane, for all practical purposes, can be considered constant.
Since the Moon's minimum orbital speed coincides with the Moon being at its furthest distance from the Earth, the Moon's minimum angular velocity is:
$\omega_{_{M_{min}}} = \frac{ V_{M_{min}} }{ R_{M_{max}} } \approx \frac{3492}{405,500} \approx 0.008611$ radians/hr.
and similarly the maximum angular velocity is
$\omega_{_{M_{max}}} = \frac{ V_{M_{max}} }{ R_{M_{min}} } \approx \frac{3895}{363300} \approx 0.010721$ radians/hr.
This represents a periodic variation of the Moon's angular velocity of nearly  20% .
The minimum ground velocity ($V_{G_{min}}$) of the Moon occurs when its orbital plane is at a maximum angle relative to the equatorial plane ($\phi_{max}$) and its angular velocity is at a maximum and it is at the highest latitude above the equator. The maximum angular velocity for the Moon is used, as it detracts from the Earth's angular velocity, which is the greatest contributor to the ground speed. Putting it all together:
$V_{G_{min}} = (\omega_{_{M_{max}}} -\omega_{_{E}} \cos \phi_{max}) R' $
and replacing $\beta$ with $\phi_{max}$ when calculating R' using the formula given earlier, the end result is:
~ -1401 km/hr or - 389 m/s.
The maximum ground velocity ($V_{G_{max}}$) also occurs when the inclination of the Moon's orbit is at a maximum angle ($\phi_{max}$), but its angular velocity should now be at a minimum and it is passing over the equator. The maximum is at this location because the the Earth tangential velocity is greatest here. The Moon's path is now at a different angle to Earth's tangential velocity, and the resultant of the two velocity vectors is found using Pythagoras and trigonometry:
The good news is that $\beta$ drops out the equation at the equator and we do not have to calculate R' separately, as it is simply equal to the equatorial radius (R).
$V_{G_{max}} = R \sqrt{ (\omega_{_{M_{\min}}} \cos \phi_{max} - \omega_{_{E}})^2+(\omega_{_{M_{min}}} \sin \phi_{max}  )^2 } $
$\approx$ -1626 km/hr or - 452 m/s.
Mathematica notebook containing the above calculations is here.
EDIT: I am now in a position to generalise the equation even further thanks to some excellent input from @Intelligentipauca in a related question in the SE math forum.
This extension allows the ground speed to be calculated at any latitude rather than just at the equator and maximum latitude.
The key is that the angle ($\theta$) between the Moon's tangential velocity vector and the equatorial plane is determined by the relationship $\cos \theta = \left( \frac{\cos \phi }{\cos \beta}\right)$.
The x component of the Moon's contribution to the total ground velocity at any given latitude $\beta$ is then $V_x = V_M'  \cos \theta$.
The angle $\phi$ can be considered as essentially constant over a short time period of less that a month, while the angle $\beta$ is constantly changing.
The y component of the Moon's contribution to the total ground velocity at any given latitude is $V_y = V_M'\sin\theta$.
The combined ground velocity due to all the components is then:
$$ V_G = \sqrt{(V_x-V_E)^2 + Vy^2}.$$
(There is no y component to the Earth's tangential velocity as it is always parallel to the equator.)

You have: (−)×≈0.00941×6378≈−1,388 km/hr.
Wouldn't this be (0.00941 - 0.26262) x 6378 = -1614 km/h?

@tansvaal Yes, it should be. Good work spotting the typo! Corrected now.

@PM2Ring Interesting. You get about 627 m/s, I get 448 m/s and the link https://what-if.xkcd.com/157/ given by Sten gets around 425 m/s. Hmmm...

@PM2Ring I upvoted both your related answers, because the presentation is professional, the research and references are extensive and the SageMath program is simply beautiful. Would have upvoted them more if I could :-)  As for my answer I have extended it to cover the more generic and realistic situation that allows for the (varying over an 18 year period) inclination of the Moon's orbital plane relative the Earth's equatorial plane, instantaneous latitude taking the Earth's oblateness into account and varying tangential velocity and radius due to the Moon's elliptical orbit into account.

@PM2Ring I now get a minimum ground speed of -389 m/s and a maximum of -452 m/s. Unfortunately our results still do not overlap, so at least one of us has made an error somewhere. I have included a link to a Mathematica notebook that might make it easier for anyone who would like to check my calculations.

While I agree that the Moon appears to move east to west in the sky which leads to the negative ground speed, I will have to think about why the Moon's shadow moves west to east at approximately 1000 miles per hour!

@PM2Ring While I am using the difference in angular velocities, I am multiplying the difference by the Earth's radius which gives the linear Cartesian velocity, since $v = \omega r$. In the more detailed analysis I am adding linear velocity vectors to get the resultant linear velocity.

@JohnHoltz I did some research and the shadow of a solar eclipse does indeed move in the opposite direction to the ground track or apparent motion of the Moon in the sky and I think I l know why. Might deserve its own question :-)

@PM2Ring The fact remains that your first observation that the tangential velocity of the Earth is the dominant factor and the motion of the Moon can only reduce that, is correct, so the ground velocity should be below 465 m/s.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
